# vb.net : How can I detect duplicates in listview?

Tags: vb.net

There is a comboBox in my program wherein you will select one from the options and when you hit enter on the amount textbox, the data is transferred to the list view...only problem is the occurence of duplicates

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim listitem As ListViewItem
    Dim amount As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal
    Dim subtract As Decimal
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    Private Sub textAmount_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textAmount.KeyDown

        total = Val(textTotal.Text)
        amount = Val(textAmount.Text)
        textAmount.MaxLength = 9

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If IsNumeric(textAmount.Text) = True Then
                If amount > 0 = True Then

                   'Need to put something here to prevent the duplicates 
                   'from being entered into the List View

                    total = total + amount
                    listitem = New ListViewItem
                    listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                    listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                    listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                    listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                    textTotal.Text = total

                    MsgBox("Invalid input", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")

                Else    
                    MsgBox("Invalid input", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox(x, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ListView1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            subtract = Val(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text)
            total = total - subtract
            textTotal.Text = total
            ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Remove()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        textTotal.Text = 0.0
        textName.Text = "Enter full name"
        textAddress.Text = "Enter full address"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you're trying to not add the *charge* more than once. I think this will help:

First look at this `Function`:

```
Private Function chargeExists(ByVal text As String) As Boolean

    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

        If lvi.Text.Equals(text) Then Return True

    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

This is how you would use the `Function`:

```
If Not chargeExists(comboCharge.Text) Then
    total = total + amount
    listitem = New ListViewItem
    listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
    listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
    listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
    listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
    ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
    textTotal.Text = total
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Your code would look something similar to this:

```
Private Sub textAmount_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textAmount.KeyDown

    total = Val(textTotal.Text)
    amount = Val(textAmount.Text)
    textAmount.MaxLength = 9

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If IsNumeric(textAmount.Text) = True Then
            If amount > 0 = True Then
                If Not chargeExists(comboCharge.Text) Then
                    total = total + amount
                    listitem = New ListViewItem
                    listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                    listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                    listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                    listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                    textTotal.Text = total
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid input", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox(x, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also I would use `MessageBox.Show`, instead of `MsgBox`.

Comment: A million thanks :D made my life easier...been trying to find a way for this to be shorter...

Comment: @ jinx88909 Yeah problem is that when I show this answer to my prof tomorrow, i will have problems trying to explain how i got this...nah i'll mention your name :3

Comment: @DatNoobPotatoPCGuy you set the text `listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text` so explain you created a function to check each `ListViewItem` for that text and only add the `ListViewItem` if it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I got tired of searching for some sort of shortcut on this thing.... so what i did was this...

```
Public Class Form1
Dim listitem As ListViewItem
Dim amount As Decimal
Dim total As Decimal
Dim subtract As Decimal
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim charge(90) As String
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long

Private Sub textAmount_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textAmount.KeyDown
    total = Val(textTotal.Text)
    amount = Val(textAmount.Text)
    textAmount.MaxLength = 9
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If IsNumeric(textAmount.Text) = True Then
            If amount > 0 = True Then


                For y = 0 To x Step -1
                    charge(y) = comboCharge.Text
```

Added tons of Conditional statements...
This is not recommended if you have a lot of options to deal with

```
                    If charge(y) = "Delivery Fee" Then
                        If a < 1 Then
                            total = total + amount
                            listitem = New ListViewItem
                            listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                            ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                            textTotal.Text = total
                            a = a + 1
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Duplicate", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                        End If
                    ElseIf charge(y) = "Cancellation Fee" Then
                        If b < 1 Then
                            total = total + amount
                            listitem = New ListViewItem
                            listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                            ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                            textTotal.Text = total
                            b = b + 1
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Duplicate", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                        End If

                    ElseIf charge(y) = "Special Handling Fee" Then
                        If c < 1 Then
                            total = total + amount
                            listitem = New ListViewItem
                            listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                            ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                            textTotal.Text = total
                            c = c + 1
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Duplicate", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                        End If

                    ElseIf charge(y) = "Assistance Fee" Then
                        If d < 1 Then
                            total = total + amount
                            listitem = New ListViewItem
                            listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                            ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                            textTotal.Text = total
                            d = d + 1
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Duplicate", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                        End If

                    ElseIf charge(y) = "Installation Fee" Then
                        If x < 1 Then
                            total = total + amount
                            listitem = New ListViewItem
                            listitem.Text = comboCharge.Text
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAmount.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textName.Text)
                            listitem.SubItems.Add(textAddress.Text)
                            ListView1.Items.Add(listitem)
                            textTotal.Text = total
                            x = x + 1
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Duplicate", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Else

                MsgBox("Invalid input", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Enter numbers only!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ListView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ListView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        subtract = Val(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text)
        total = total - subtract
        textTotal.Text = total
        ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Remove()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    textTotal.Text = 0.0
    textName.Text = "Enter full name"
    textAddress.Text = "Enter full address"
    comboCharge.Text = "Select type of charge"
    textAmount.Text = "0.0"
End Sub

Private Sub buttonclear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonclear.Click
    textTotal.Text = 0.0
    textName.Text = "Enter full name"
    textAddress.Text = "Enter full address"
    comboCharge.Text = "Select type of charge"
    textAmount.Text = "0.0"
    subtract = Val(ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text)
    total = total - subtract
    textTotal.Text = total
    ListView1.Items(0).Remove()

  End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: By the way please discard the array CHARGE(90)...forgot to remove it...it has no use

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41595382/edit) your answer instead of commenting on it (which is also available via the link under your answer and above the comments)